# UnicodeEncodeError by using DecisionTree

Tags: python, scikit-learn

my code is below

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import tree

Model_Dev_Val = pd.read_excel("data2.xlsx")

target = Model_Dev_Val[['source_2']]

model_train, model_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Model_Dev_Val, target,test_size = 0.5, random_state = 40,stratify = target)

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit( model_train,y_train)
```

But it throws an error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'decimal' codec can't encode characters in
>   position 0-2: invalid decimal Unicode string
>
> data2.xlsx include some Chinese, and the data has been cleaned.

Comment: There will probably be an issue with the chinese characters in your file.

Comment: i have thought about it. and i take a right data.xlsx from my boss. and it error:ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').

Comment: Then there is probably a `NaN`, `infinity` or too large number in there

Comment: yes ,i know, but i run ok in my boss's computer

Comment: If the same code runs fine on his computer, than it might be caused by your machine having less memory, a different version of python, a different version of scikit-learn, or even something else.

Comment: sry,pal. maybe it's Chinese matter.and the next , my boss just run train_test_split ,doesnt run tree.thx

Comment: I will add this as an answer for easier future reference.

Answer (score 0):

There will probably be an issue with the Chinese characters in your file.

Other errors thrown (`ValueError`) might mean there is probably a `NaN`, `infinity` or too large number in there

If the same code runs fine on your boss' computer, than it might be caused by your machine having less memory, a different version of python, a different version of scikit-learn, or even something else.

Comment: Everything you use should be converted to numbers. But you can do this with words, e.g. assign each word a different number, or use [one-hot encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) to represent your words.

Comment: This might also help you: [using string data in scikit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-deal-with-string-data-or-trees-graphs)

Comment: THX,bro,,,,,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this can solve your problem because I can not reproduce your problem, but you may have a try:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: same problem,sry pal